# Can "having an affair" work both ways?

Tags: phrases, word-order

The married person in an affair is clearly having one, but is the unmarried participant?

To use a well-known real-life example, Bill Clinton had an affair with Monica Lewinsky. But did Monica Lewinsky have an affair with Bill Clinton?

Answer (score 2):

it could probably be [two-way:](http://www.wordnik.com/words/affair)

> A romantic and sexual relationship,
>   sometimes one of brief duration,
>   between two people who are not married
>   to each other.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the expression is used only when referring to married people.

> His wife is having an affair.

Comment: Though it is most commonly used that way, it can be used when neither participant is married (as a synonym for "relationship")...

Comment: @psmears: but this usage is quite obscure...

Comment: @Jimi Oke - I wouldn't say "obscure" at all - though perhaps "outdated"...  I have heard my older (60 and above) friends use it to refer to college romances; it appears frequently in Frank Sinatra songs (others too, but he's the first to come to mind);  "Love Affair" (1939, remade in 1994 and in 1957 as "An Affair to Remember"); others will come to mind.  I would say that in the past, "affair" was shorthand for "love affair", and now it's generally shorthand for "extramarital affair."  Just when that shift happened, I couldn't say.

Comment: This usage of 'affair' for 'love affair' is very common in India even today.